# Login page get refreshed when I log an admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to redirect the admin user to dasheboard  but the Admin-login  page always get refreshed, I set up admins tables and ran the migrations and I added one admin with tinkle command

AdminLoginController.php

```
<?php

       namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Admin;




            class  AdminLoginController extends Controller
              {

          public function login(Request $request){

              $this->validate($request,[

       'email'=>'required|email',
       'password'=>'required|min:6'
   ]);
      if ((Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) ){

        return redirect()->intended('Admin.dasheboard');
    }
          return redirect()->back();

       }

public function show(){
return view(' Admin.admin-login');
     }
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
   Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@show');
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\AdminLoginController@show');
     Route::post('/login', 'Admin\AdminLoginController@login');
      });
```

Auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

     'users' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'users',
     ], 
    'admins' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'admins',
     ],
],
```

For the blade page it has:

```
   <form action="/admin/login" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one problem.

1. the `intended()` function take a url not route name so

   use `return redirect()->intended('/');`

   instead of `return redirect()->intended('Admin.dasheboard');`
2. if you want to use route name you have to name your rout in **routes.php**

   ```
   Route::get('/', 'Admin\AdminController@show')->name('Admin.dasheboard');
   ```

   then use this code into **AdminLoginController.php**

   ```
   if ((Auth::guard('admins')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) ){
       return redirect()->route('Admin.dasheboard');
   }
   ```

You may find more about [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes)

**Update:**

3. You admin guard called `admins` into **auth.php** file

   so you have to call `Auth::guard('admins')` with (s) charcted added.

Comment: Thank you for the comment , but it keeps refreshing ://

Comment: It means that your credentials are wrong, Are you sure the password has encrypted during registration process and it's a `bcrypt` password into your database

Comment: I've encrypted manually a password with " hash generator "  but the issue persists...

Comment: Try to use `dd('something')` inside `if()` statement and find out if your credentials works.

Comment: no way my friend :( would u like to check by yourself?

Comment: Did your code died and showed you the message `something` or not?

Comment: There is no message at all... as I told u I get back the same page each time I login..

Comment: OK just change it `Auth::guard('admin')` to `Auth::guard('admins')` note the letter `s` added to `admin`

Comment: I already declared a guard called " admin" in auth.php file so it will generate  **Auth guard [admins] is not defined.** and that what happened...

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

    ],